# Reloading altered keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, ukelele

When using Ukulele, how can I get an altered keyboard layout in `~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts` to be reloaded without rebooting?

Comment: Are you talking about a Ukelele layout?  Do you have to reboot every time you want to use it?  Normally all you have to do is logout/login when you first install it.

Comment: @TomGewecke,
Yes. If I add one with a new name it is available right away, but if I overwrite an old, it only reloads after a reboot.

Comment: I doubt you can avoid that.  Ask on the group devoted to Ukelele.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Answer (score 1):

According to a [thread in the Ukelele group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ukelele-users/reload%7Csort:date/ukelele-users/kLWHQsUBJgM/dMSdu9UxEQAJ), changing the key layout ID before installing can cause OS X to load the new layout. This should be done on a working copy of the layout bundle, not an installed one, and may not work in newer versions of OS X (I could not get it to work under High Sierra). If changing the ID doesn't work for you, logging out and back in again should reload keyboard layouts.

Steps:

1. Open a working copy of the layout bundle in Ukelele. Note this can't be an installed, active layout (i.e. one in a relevant "Library/Keyboard Layouts" folder).
2. Generate a new ID:

   1. In Ukelele's list of keyboard layouts for the bundle, right-click the layout and choose "Set Keyboard Name and Script…".
   2. Change the script (e.g. from "Unicode" to "Roman"), taking note of the original value.
   3. Click OK
   4. Repeat the last 3 steps and change the script back to the original value.
   5. Save the layout.
3. If an older copy of the layout is installed, remove it from the relevant "Keyboard Layout" folder.
4. Copy the updated layout to the relevant "Keyboard Layout" folder.

Under the hood, this changes the "id" attribute of the root `<keyboard>` element in `Contents/Resources/<name>.layout` within the bundle.